# C++ templated function wrapper arguments using const& versus &

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

Creating a wrapper function for a constructor such as the following compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class wrapper
{
public:
  template <typename A0>
  T* operator () (const A0& a0) const
  {
    return new T(a0);
  }
};

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int i) { std::cout << "Foo:Foo(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  wrapper<Foo>()(42);
  return 0;
}
```

But the code does not compile when I update the line:

```
T* operator () (const A0& a0) const
```

to:

```
T* operator () (A0& a0) const
```

My guess is this has to do with the rvalue '42' not being bindable to to a non-const reference. But when I make the reference const this will mean that I could never call a constructor that actually takes a non-const reference. Can someone explain what is going on here, and what is the right thing to do to make it work?

Comment: Declaring a parameter const is a promise to the callers that the function will not change the parameter.  It increases the types you can pass into it.

Answer (score 1):

> My guess is this has to do with the rvalue '42' not being bindable to to a non-const reference.

Yes. Correct.

> But when I make the reference const this will mean that I could never call a constructor that actually takes a non-const reference.

No. Incorrect. You can still call it with non-const reference. In fact, that is how const-ness works : non-const reference/pointer/object can implicitly convert into const reference/pointer/object, but vice-versa is not true.

So try it out.

Comment: I did try it out, before I posted this question. When I change the Foo constructor to be `Foo(int& i) { ...` and make the wrapper function call operator take a const reference instead of just a reference it will not compile because the constructor does not take a const reference. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @user1220090: You should use `Foo(int const &i)`. But since it is built-in type, a more sane choice is this : `Foo(int i)`. That is, just pass by value.

Comment: Okay, using `int` was a bad choice. Let me see if I can clarify my question, what if the constructor was `Foo(Bar &b)` where `Bar` was some other type that I wanted to pass to the constructor by non-const reference? How can I achieve this?

Comment: @user1220090: then as I said, it should be `Foo(Bar const &b)`.

Comment: but I want to pass `b` as a non-const reference. If I do as you suggest then I can't modify any of the fields in `b` or call any non-const methods of `b`.

Comment: @user1220090: You seem to be very much confused. Your question says something, and you're saying it here something else. Anyway, pass by non-const reference then, but you would not be able to pass *rvalue* to it, nor can you pass const reference.